# How to add Crypto Certificate in IBM Datapower using API Call

Tags: ibm-datapower

I want to add crypto certificate in IBM Datapower using API Call. How can I implement this Kindly help me. I already read all the documentation about **REST Management Interface** and **XML Management Interface** I did not found any good information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in two separate steps, upload the file/s and then create the IDCRED/CERT objects.

Using SOMA (XML Management) you'd use `dp:set-file` and with the REST management you'd need to base64 encode the file and use the endpoint `/mgmt/filestore/{domain}/{directory}/{filename}`.

After the file/s is/are uploaded you can go ahead and create the CERT object/s point to the files.

Have a look at the awesome Config-Manager which can help you with a number of tasks; https://github.com/ibm-datapower/datapower-configuration-manager